# how to see which process is using which port in windows 8

Tags: windows, port, eclipse, task-manager, tomcat

I am trying to start the Tomcat server at my pc by eclipse. But it is showing the following  message

```
Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).
```

I am using windows 8. In windows 7, in task manager it can be found the process with its port number.

I have used the `netstat -aon | findstr :` command to find out the process that are using ports 8005,8080,8009. But the process id is shown by it, i am not finding such PID in PID list in the taskmanger in the task manager.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Resource Manager, open up the `TCP Connections` screen and look at the `Local Port` column and find the ports you want free. Then check the corresponding name in the `Image` column.

[image]

Comment: sorry, i am searching for port number....

Comment: @BlackSwan Sorry I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @BlackSwan I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to see which process is using which port in windows

Use [tcpview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) from [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals):

> TCPView is a Windows program that will show you detailed listings of all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system, including the local and remote addresses and state of TCP connections.
>
> On Windows Server 2008, Vista, and XP, TCPView also reports the name of the process that owns the endpoint. TCPView provides a more informative and conveniently presented subset of the Netstat program that ships with Windows.
>
> The TCPView download includes Tcpvcon, a command-line version with the same functionality.

Source: [tcpview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx)

Example output (sorted by local port):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.